# Estimating the "goodness" of a proposition

Tags: logic

I am a software developer who is studying mathematics and logic. I made this proposition, I wanted to see how good it is, from your perspective as experts.

> It is not actually known whether answering some question, is easier than asking another question which would yield a predefined expected answer. Even in well-defined sciences, it seems hard to ask a question which would generate an expected answer for that question.

Example:
Imagine a paragraph of text, talking about some field in a neat and organized way. Now think of this text as an answer to a question, I believe it is hard, to form a question which would generate that answer you imagined.

Notice that I am not asking you to look at someone's answer, and guess the question who triggered the answer.

Is this proposition easy to be understood by an average-intelligence person, or is it too vague even for an intelligent person?

Comment: What do you mean by the words "subjectivity" and "objectivity"? They are not normally degreed properties. There's a use that's relative like this in Kierkegaard.

Comment: Subjective matters like relationships, love, psychology...etc. Objective matters like well-defined scientific theories. Another way to put it, subjective means opinionated while objective means based on proven or standard metrics.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea what you're trying to say in your quotation... do you want to try again in normal English?

Comment: This statement is not well-formed in English, which makes it all but impossible to evaluate in terms of its logic.

Comment: Kenan, welcome to philosophy.SE. I'm having a difficulty parsing the sentence. I understood bits and pieces, but am wondering what the context is. Could you say something about the project you're pursuing? Understanding what you want to say might help make sense of the question you asked.

Comment: Rephrased the proposition and added an example.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to say something like this:

*Every question and answer have a **subject matter**. The more objective the subject matter is, the more likely an answer to a question about that subject matter is to be either "yes" or "no".*

I don't really think that's right, because I don't think it's a matter of the objectivity of the subject matter, per se, that is at stake. It's a matter of being able to ask well-defined questions that permit of well-defined answers. There are subjective-ish subject matters about which well defined questions can be asked. "Is Milton a better poet than Blake?" The answer to that question is either yes or no--regardless of how anybody happens to feel about it. The difficulty is coming up with objective criteria by which to tell which case obtains.

Perhaps in some general sense objectivity of subject matter tracks well-definedness of questions, but I think we'd need to see some argument for that.

Here's another thought--maybe it is the ability to figure out decision procedures for well-defined questions that lead us to gain objective knowledge about some subject areas . . .

Comment: You skipped "It is controversial whether answering a question, is easier than asking a question which would yield a predefined expected answer". And I meant, the more objective the question is, the more controversial will it be to determine which is easier (to answer the question, or to ask a question which would yield an expected answer).

Comment: Why exactly do you care about whether it is easier to ask the question or answer it? I don't see exactly what this is driving at, and I think that might really help.

Comment: Notice that, in the first place, that's not a question I want to know the answer of. I don't care about it, and answering this question could take very long discussion. My concern is about the logical model of the paragraph.